# Scroll down to the specific part of page when a linkbutton is clicked using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a lengthy asp.net page. An HTML table in the page has a link with `<a>`. when the link is clicked the page shows the textbox using javascript and takes me to the top part of the page. Instead, i want to see the part of the page that has the link and textbox. It should automatically scroll down to that part once the page refreshes. How is that possible?

I have tried using Linkbutton instead of  but have issues with javascript.

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $("#aChangeDefault").click
    ( 

        function()
        {
            alert('hi');
            //$("#<%=trChangeLoc.ClientID %>").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#<%=rowChangeLoc.ClientID %>").fadeIn(1000); 
        }
    )

    $("#btnClose").click
    (
       function()
        {
            $("#<%=rowChangeLoc.ClientID %>").fadeOut(1000);    

            if(document.getElementById("<%=divSearchResult.ClientID %>").style.display != "none")
            {
                $("#<%=divSearchResult.ClientID %>").fadeOut(1000);
            } 
            //$("#<%=trChangeLoc.ClientID %>").fadeOut(10);                            
        }
    )       
}

);
```

The Linkbutton is here :

```
 <asp:LinkButton id="aChangeDefault" runat="server" style="font-size: 12px;font-family:Arial;vertical-align:bottom;" ToolTip = "Click here to set your town as default location" Text ="Change Location" > </asp:LinkButton>
```

And the portion that shows up when the link is clicked is here:

```
  <input id="btnClose" type="button" class="closeButton2" language="javascript" onclick="return btnClose_onclick()" />
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="searchheadder" style="color: #000000; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 4px;">
                                        LOCATION: </span>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangedLocation" onkeyup="doCapitalize();" runat="server" Height="19px"
                                        Width="200px" CssClass="textBox" Style="margin-right: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
     <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ACE1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtChangedLocation" ServicePath="../AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionSetCount="10" EnableCaching="true" CompletionInterval="0" ></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
      <asp:Button ID="btnGetNewList" BorderWidth="0" CssClass="searchButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetNewList_Click" />  </div>
```

Appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` only affects the position of the page in your browser when a PostBack occurs, and if you're using JavaScript you don't want a PostBack to happen. If you're doing everything in JavaScript, it sounds like the problem is that when you click a link, the browser's default behavior is to *follow* the link, even if it's to a location on the same page. In some browsers, for the click event to register on an `<a>` tag, the `href` property must have a value, so it's common practice to use a blank anchor name as the `href`:

```
<a onClick="MyJavaScriptFunction()" href="#">Click here</a>
```

What this is actually telling the browser to do is to call your function `MyJavaScriptFunction()` and unless that function evaluates to false, it will then follow the anchor to the top of the page, which is where `href="#"` takes you. You can either finish your `onClick` with `return false;` or else change your JavaScript function to always return `false`, either way it will keep the browser from following the link:

```
<a onClick="MyJavaScriptFunction();return false;" href="#">Click here</a>
```

Comment: this is just so meaningful. I am glad i asked it here. It worked. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if the page is reloading perhaps you can use a named anchor to have the browser go to the section of the page you want automatically.